# Angular does not pick $scope.variable_name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my HTML code.

```
<div class="container" ng-app="mintcart">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="categoriesctrl">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="session.sid" value="<?php echo session_id();?>"/>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    while($i < count($list)){
                        $name = $list[$i]['categoryName'];
                        $id = $list[$i]['id'];
                        $normalUrl = $list[$i]['normalImageUrl'];
                        $hoverUrl = $list[$i]['hoverImageUrl'];
                        if($i == 0){
                            echo "<li role='presentation' class='active' ng-click='loadproducts($id)'><a href='#' >$name</a></li>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<li role='presentation' ng-click='loadproducts($id)'><a href='#''>$name</a></li>";
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

ANd below is my JS code.

```
var app = angular.module('mintcart',[]);

app.controller('categoriesctrl', function($scope, $http){
    var auth = {};
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseurl + 'api/get_product_categories'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.categories = response.data.categories;
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

    $scope.loadproducts = function(item_id) {
        alert($scope.session.sid);
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: baseurl + 'api/get_items_in_category_cart/' + item_id
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data.products;
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
        //$scope.Language = lang;
    }; 

});
```

When the loadproducts function is called the alert($scope.session.sid); gives me "undefined". I can't understand why my element is not being picked up.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does the value get assigned?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes. it does. When I see the source code, the session value is there.

Comment: You are setting the value into the input on your server. Angular does not know this. As far as Angular is concerned, $scope.session.sid is undefined. To use 2-way binding properly (ng-model) you need to assign the value to the $scope, not the element.

Comment: `ng-model` doesn't supports input with `type="hidden"`...

Comment: @PankajParkar thank you for tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php works on the server side, you need to set the variable using a javascript not on the view.

Create a variable in JavaScript which gets the returned content of PHP.

```
var sessionid = <?php echo session_id();?>
```

then , you can access the variable in controller,

```
 var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("categoriesctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.session.sid = sessionid ;
  console.log($scope.session.sid);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. seems like i need to get my head around the php,javascript and angular differences.